# Swing JTable sort by Date

Tags: java, swing, date, sorting, jtable

I would like to sort a Jtable by the date in one column, but only display the date in the format dd-MM-yyyy. So all entries are the same and only differ in the seconds which are not visible.

I have a TableModel which gets the data with the following method:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

    Object[][] tableData = new Object[rowDataMap.keySet().size()][1];
    int index = 0;
    for (Long key : pane.nqm_messages.keySet())
    {
        Date date = rowDataMap.get(key);

        SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
        String outputDate = form.format(date);

        tableData[index][0] = outputDate;

        index++;
    }
    return tableData[row][col];
}
```

And here is my TableRowSorter where I want to sort the rows:

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();

SortKey sortKey;
sorter.setComparator( 0, new Comparator<String>() {  
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)  {
        //Sort dd-MM-yyyy 
    }
});
```

If I do it like that I cant sort it because the strings are obv. all the same. 
When I directly use the date object like that

> tableData[index][0] = date

I do not know how to display it in the correct format but the sorting can be done.

How can I achieve both?

Comment: don't return a string representation of the value, return the value itself and implement columnClass accordingly

Comment: Apart from what kleopatra has pointed out, it is woefully inefficient to try and build the display data on each requests of the cell

Comment: other than that, your model implementation looks fishy: a) why to create the complete 2d array when you just need to return a single value? b) why do create that single value on each call to getValueAt? If it's so dynamic, that it might change between calls, the model is most probably misbehaving by not notifying its listeners as needed c) formatting a Date is the responsibility of a renderer (not of the model)

Comment: thx for the advices. I´ll take a look at it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't convert the `Date` objects to `String`.  Instead, use them directly within the model.  It's not the models responsibility to suggest formatting, instead use a `TableCellRenderer`.

Allow `getValueAt` to return the `Date` object.

Modify the table model and override the `getColumnClass` method and return the approiate class for the hiven columns (like `Date.class`).

The table, will by default, format the `Date` objects for you.

You can supply your own `TableCellRenderer` if the default one is not to your liking.

See [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details, pay special attention to [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the `display` and `inner` logic differs you should consider a **TableModel** and a **CellRenderer**. Why don't you add a CellRenderer on the date column? The cell renderer renders the date object using the SimpleDateFormat, however the inner values remain as Date objects. That way the sorting should work correctly, because the sorter works on the inner values.

Comment: If the `TableModel#getColumnClassAt` returned `Data.class`, the table would have used it's own, default table cell renderer.  However +1 for suggesting the use of a `CellRenderer` non the less

Comment: I think the CellRenderer overrides whatever default renderer is used with the getColumnClassAt method. but i could be wrong

Comment: Yeah, that's my point, but you can supply your own if needed.